# Does the number of MQ process amqrmppa increase or decrease automatically?

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

i've got a question with MQ process **`amqrmppa`**. i know it's used for channel client connection and each one process can have up to 64 threads running inside. The number of such process would increase when more connections come in. But will the number of `amqrmppa` decrease when client disconnect and connections have gone?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, assuming that the channel definition specifies threads instead of processes, the number of processes does decrease but not immediately.  Because spinning the processes up and shutting them down takes time and resources, WMQ will leave channel pooling processes running for a while after a channel shuts down in order to reuse them.  This optimizes performance but makes it harder to predict when a channel pooling process will be reaped.  Also, it is possible that for any given process, one or more of its threads hosts an active channel even though others have shut down.  You may have several processes running, each hosting one or two channels and WMQ will not consolidate open connections into a single process just to reduce the process count.  (That would require renegotiation of the channels, SSL sessions, etc.)  So thread usage is a bit more dynamic than process usage.

Finally, please note that this behavior is not documented and thus subject to change from version to version and even from fix pack to fix pack.  For example, behavior of channel agents changed significantly when conversation sharing was introduced.  This response is based on my experience and your mileage may vary.

Comment: i love the response based on your experience. Thanks @T.Rob, it's clear to me now.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, all except one process will go away. The last amqrmppa process is kept around to minimize the cost of re-establishing amqrmppa processes.